# Efficiently Querying Core Data with Multiple Stores: Finding Set Differences and Highest Priority

Tags: ios, swift, database, core-data, cloudkit

I'm working on a Core Data application with two separate stores: **WordStore** and **StatusStore**. These stores serve distinct purposes:

- **StatusStore** contains a single entity called **Status** with fields:

  - `word`: A Chinese word (Unique Key).
  - `status`: Either "learning" or "known".
- **WordStore** contains a single entity called **Word** with fields:

  - `word`: A Chinese word (Unique Key).
  - `frequency`: An integer representing the importance of the word.
  - `zhuyin`: Phonetic description of `word`
  - `meaning`: English Definition of `word`

The motivation behind having two separate stores is that **WordStore** stores a large amount of data on the device, while **StatusStore** is intended to be synchronized with CloudKit.

I'm seeking guidance on how to efficiently perform a query that accomplishes the following tasks:

1. Find the set of **NewWords**, defined as the set difference between **WordStore** and **StatusStore**:

   - `NewWords = WordStore - StatusStore`.
2. Identify the word within **NewWords** with the highest `frequency`

I've previously attempted fetching all records from both stores and then using set operations to achieve this, but it feels inefficient. I'm hoping to discover a more efficient and optimized approach to accomplish this task.

Any insights or suggestions on how to efficiently handle this scenario would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all I don't think there is any way to "join" the stores so you must probably load the objects into memory. Secondly your logic seems a bit flawed. In point 2 you want to find the words with highest priority but the result from point 1 are only words from WordStore and the don't have a priority so there is nothing to identify. So either you can skip point 2 or you need to rethink your logic.

Comment: Sorry i had mixed up the titles for my stores. Fixed now. So it looks like my original approach is maybe the best i can do in this situation.

Comment: The only other approach I can think of is to duplicate the `status` property into WordStore as well as keeping it in StatusStore. You may need to add an update date to both stores as well so that you can synchronise changes to WordStore across devices. Once you have `status` in WordStore you can query for words with no status and sort by frequency.

Comment: Also, how big is WordStore? Megabytes? Gigabytes? If it is, say, less than 20mB it might be simpler just to have one store.

Comment: @Paulw11 Good point. The json from which the store is created is 5-6mb. If I went with that approach would it be simply creating another entity for status and then creating a relationship between the two entities? Then just store this one table in cloud kit.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/linking_data_between_two_core_data_stores